# How can i automatically add tag to cloudinary image upload from react code

Tags: reactjs, file-upload, next.js, cloudinary

I need to tag images uploaded from my web to cloudinary because i need to track them later to delete if not useful

i tried adding the tags to the cloudinary formdata payload, but i doubt it solves the case, am also not using the cloudinary upload widget.

Comment: Could you share the code used when you mentioned you added the tags to the formdata? Did you encounter an error when sending that request - if so, what was the error response?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.